# How to iterate over nested dictionaries (with lists) and adding values together but maintaining strings in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have data in two separate objects of the same shape, and I want to add the values together. The issue is that each object is a dictionary of dictionaries of lists of dictionaries. I have provided an example of what it looks like below.

```
data1 = {
    'months': {
        'type1': [
            {'name': 'Month 1', 'value': 10, 'sequence': 1}, 
            {'name': 'Month 2', 'value': 20, 'sequence': 2}, 
            {'name': 'Month 3', 'value': 30, 'sequence': 3}
        ],
        'type2': [
            {'name': 'Month 1', 'value': 10, 'sequence': 1}, 
            {'name': 'Month 2', 'value': 20, 'sequence': 2}, 
            {'name': 'Month 3', 'value': 30, 'sequence': 3}
        ]
    },
    'years': {
        'type1': [
            {'name': 'Year 1', 'value': 10, 'sequence': 1},
            {'name': 'Year 2', 'value': 20, 'sequence': 2},
            {'name': 'Year 3', 'value': 30, 'sequence': 3}
        ],
        'type2': [
            {'name': 'Year 1', 'value': 10, 'sequence': 1},
            {'name': 'Year 2', 'value': 20, 'sequence': 2},
            {'name': 'Year 3', 'value': 30, 'sequence': 3}
        ]
    }
}
```

The above is a simplified version of what the actual data looks like. For sake of this example, let us say that `data2` would be identical to `data1` with regards to values. Note: they are identical with regards to shape.

I would like to be able to iterate over these nested dictionary/lists and add the `value`s together for each month within each type, and maintain all other necessary information.

I.e. `data1` + `data2` = `data_output` (provided below).

```
data_output = {
    'months': {
        'type1': [
            {'name': 'Month 1', 'value': 20, 'sequence': 1}, 
            {'name': 'Month 2', 'value': 40, 'sequence': 2}, 
            {'name': 'Month 3', 'value': 60, 'sequence': 3}
        ],
        'type2': [
            {'name': 'Month 1', 'value': 20, 'sequence': 1}, 
            {'name': 'Month 2', 'value': 40, 'sequence': 2}, 
            {'name': 'Month 3', 'value': 60, 'sequence': 3}
        ]
    },
    'years': {
        'type1': [
            {'name': 'Year 1', 'value': 20, 'sequence': 1},
            {'name': 'Year 2', 'value': 40, 'sequence': 2},
            {'name': 'Year 3', 'value': 60, 'sequence': 3}
        ],
        'type2': [
            {'name': 'Year 1', 'value': 20, 'sequence': 1},
            {'name': 'Year 2', 'value': 40, 'sequence': 2},
            {'name': 'Year 3', 'value': 60, 'sequence': 3}
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried applying the solutions listed in the following answers, but with no success (which may be due to my misunderstanding since I am new to Python):

- [Python iterate over multi value nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646795/python-iterate-over-multi-value-nested-dictionary)
- [Iterate over nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335096/iterate-over-nested-dictionary)
- [iterate over nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913780/iterate-over-nested-dictionaries)
- [Iterate over Nested dictionary with similar keys but different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540499/iterate-over-nested-dictionary-with-similar-keys-but-different-values)
- [Python how to iterate over nested dictionary and change values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810062/python-how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionary-and-change-values)

Based on the above links, I understand that variations on this question have been asked before, but I cannot seem to make their solutions work for me, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What specific code did you try to use? What was the problem with it? This is not a matter of luck.

Comment: Please see [ask], in particular please create a [mre]. Also [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Apologies @mkrieger1 "with no luck" is idiomatic English which means "with no success"; I am not suggesting there is any luck involved. I will amend this. And I appreciate your link to the How to Ask. However, as you can see, I have provided a minimal reproducible example of the data, plus the exact desired output. I have also broken down exactly what I need to be summed together, and at no point did I say just "Someone help me". I, admittedly, have not provided all my failed attempts, since I believe that they would not be useful, especially since I am fairly new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dictionaries have the same structure as the one you mentioned in your question, you can do something like the following (assuming `data1` and `data2` as input data):

```py
import copy
data_out = copy.deepcopy(data1)

# months, years,...
for i in data_out:
    # type 1,2,3,...
    for j in data_out[i]:
        # tuples for months/years
        for k in range(len(data_out[i][j])):
            print(i,j,k)
            data_out[i][j][k]['value'] += data2[i][j][k]['value']
```

which produces the following `data_out` when `data2=data1`:

```py
{
   "months":{
      "type1":[
         {
            "name":"Month 1",
            "value":20,
            "sequence":1
         },
         {
            "name":"Month 2",
            "value":40,
            "sequence":2
         },
         {
            "name":"Month 3",
            "value":60,
            "sequence":3
         }
      ],
      "type2":[
         {
            "name":"Month 1",
            "value":20,
            "sequence":1
         },
         {
            "name":"Month 2",
            "value":40,
            "sequence":2
         },
         {
            "name":"Month 3",
            "value":60,
            "sequence":3
         }
      ]
   },
   "years":{
      "type1":[
         {
            "name":"Year 1",
            "value":20,
            "sequence":1
         },
         {
            "name":"Year 2",
            "value":40,
            "sequence":2
         },
         {
            "name":"Year 3",
            "value":60,
            "sequence":3
         }
      ],
      "type2":[
         {
            "name":"Year 1",
            "value":20,
            "sequence":1
         },
         {
            "name":"Year 2",
            "value":40,
            "sequence":2
         },
         {
            "name":"Year 3",
            "value":60,
            "sequence":3
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In case not all your dictionaries have the same format, you should put `if` statements checking the existence of the keys.

Comment: Thank you @nima72 - I think this should work. There is a slight difference that might require an `if` statement, but I will have a play around to see if it works. Thanks!